# What changed with timidity, alsa and jack in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, sound, alsa, jack

I (just) upgraded from 11.4 to 11.10 and noticed some differences in the behavior of 
timidity.

I used to (11.4) exectute
`>timidity midifile.midi`
without running jackd, and thus using alsa (or pulseaudio?) to produce sound from midi files.

Now having upgraded, this does not work -- currently this command just freezes if jack is not running.

If jack is running, it does work but there is an initial audio glitch (noise burst at
the start of playback, analogous to the sound of a plug being inserted) that I'd rather 
not have to deal with.

All the indications that I have is that in 11.10 `timidity` will only work (albeit glitchy) with jack on, whereas in 11.4 it did not require this.

- Is there any way to restore `timidity`'s non-jack operation in 11.10?
- Is there a way to get rid of the audio glitch in with jack operation?
- Overall, what underlying changes in these programs and the audio infrastructure are behind this?

Comment: Verified that this not a problem with timidity alone (same version of timidity run on FC15 doesn't have this problem).

Comment: Changed from jackd2 to jackd1 package -- no significant change in behaviour.

Comment: After this change, timidity just seemed to work with and without jack, but the initial noise burst (as if a large number were fed to the output at startup) still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The initial glitch sound persists in 12.04]

However, it can be avoided with the commandline option `--output-24bit`, which also gives somewhat richer sound.